# While loop behaving unexpectedly

Tags: c++, c, msp430

I am not sure if this problem is compiler specific or not, but I'll ask anyways. I'm using CCS (Code Composer Studio), which is an IDE from texas instruments to program the MSP430 microcontroller.

As usual, I'm making the beginner program of making the LED blink, located in the last bit of the P1OUT register. Here's the code that DOESN'T work (I've omitted some of the other declarations, which are irrelevant):

```
while(1){
        int i;

        P1OUT ^= 0x01;

        i = 10000;
        while(i != 0){
            i--;
        }

    }
```

Now, here's the loop that DOES work:

```
while(1){
    int i;

    P1OUT ^= 0x01;

    i = 0;
    while(i < 10000){
        i++;
    }

}
```

The two statements should be equivalent, but in the first instance, the LED stays on and doesn't blink, while in the second, it works as planned.

I'm thinking it has to do with some optimization done by the compiler, but I have no idea as to what specifically may be wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's likely that the optimiser happened to spot that in the first case the loop was a no-op, but didn't spot the equivalent optimisation in the second case.  If you want something to occur periodically, you should use a dedicated timer facility (most microcontrollers have configurable hardware timers).

Comment: Is your compiler able to produce assembler output?

Comment: Try `volatile int i;`. This forces the compiler to evaluate the code some bit more. Meta-question: can code containing `volatile` variables still be optimized away? (Gut feeling answer: sure...)

Comment: @Jongware I tried to find some way to visualize the assembler output, but the compiler isn't very helpful...
Using volatile did the trick, but I'm really surprised with this flaw.. how can I predict these sort of optimization problems?

Comment: It's not a flaw, it's just how stuff works.  In 'real' systems, such a delay whould be provided by an OS call like Sleep(), and so the loop would not get optimized out.

Comment: The only flaw here is with your code, not with your compiler. I'm pretty sure no reputable source informed you that a while loop which has no observable behavior should take a certain amount of time to execute.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley To be fair, the OP did say this was a beginner program, and this *is* based on the sample program shown on [TI's website](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Blink_your_first_LED), which one could argue is a reputable source. :-).

Answer (score 3):

The code is probably being optimised away as dead-code.  You don't want to spin like that anyway, it's terribly wasteful on CPU cycles.  You want to simply call `usleep`, something like:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int microseconds = // number of 1000ths of milliseconds to wait
while(1){
    P1OUT ^= 0x01;
    usleep(microseconds);
}
```

Comment: Does the MSP430 standard library have a `usleep` function? I'd be surprised if it did.

Comment: @Gabe - I was thinking that too.  MSP430 does not typicaly run Linux - it's barely above a toaster-controller:)

Comment: @Gabe please see [this](http://mykyta.info/a/embedded/msp430/group___m_o_d___s_l_e_e_p.html)

Comment: That `usleep` implementation is still a timing loop; it's just calibrated to a clock frequency that's set at compile time. In other words, it's better than the arbitrary loop the OP had, but it's still "wasting" CPU cycles.

Comment: If the goal is to not waste CPU cycles, use a timer and interrupt when the timeout occurs. The CPU can then be put to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

CCS can optimize code in a way you could never expect (also check the optimization levels in the project properties). Easiest way is to declare the variable with volatile keyword and you are done.